# strange behaviour removing elements from a listview

Tags: listview, javafx, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to move items from one ListView to another using drag and drop. On the setDragDropped method of the destination I put this simple code (listaOrigen is the source listView where the dragAndDrop began:

```
System.out.println("items size before moving = " + items.size());
List<EpisodioUIBean> uiBeans =   listaOrigen.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
System.out.println("beans size to move = " + uiBeans.size());
items.addAll(uiBeans);
System.out.println("items size after moving = " + items.size());
System.out.println("items in the source list before moving = " +    listaOrigen.getItems().size());
listaOrigen.getItems().removeAll(uiBeans);
System.out.println("items in the source list after moving " + uiBeans.size() + " items = " + listaOrigen.getItems().size());
```

The annoying output of the lines above is

```
items size before moving = 10
beans size to move = 1
items size after moving = 11
items in the source list before moving = 172
items in the source list after moving 1 items = 169
```

How can this happen?

I can reproduce the result with this runnable program:

```
package tree;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViews extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("ListViews");

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Hola", "Hola", "Hallo", "Hola");
        ListView<String> listView1 = new ListView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(list));
        ListView<String> listView2 = new ListView<>();
        VBox root = new VBox();
        Button b = new Button("Move selected Items");
        b.setOnAction(evt -> {
            List<String> strings = listView1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
            listView2.getItems().addAll(strings);
            listView1.getItems().removeAll(strings);
        });
        root.getChildren().add(b);
        root.getChildren().add(listView1);
        root.getChildren().add(listView2);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Just select the first "Hola" item and click the Button. All three "Hola" items dissapear from the first ListView!

Comment: duplicates in source? hard to tell without a runnable example - please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `removeAll` requires that the collection you pass as an argument does not change during the process of removing them from the target list. While it's difficult to see this being an issue when there is only one element to remove, you are violating this rule (because if an item is removed from the backing list, it is also removed from the selected items). It's impossible to know if this is the only problem from the code you've posted, but try creating a new list with the selected items and passing that to `removeAll(...)`

Comment: I've found a workaround creating a new List based on the selectedIndices. Thanks for your ideas!